# Find Array index that contains string

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have file with tags and targets, this is example:

```
TAG1|TARGET1,TARGET2
TAG2|TARGET3,TARGET4
```

I start by creating String Array using File.ReadAllLines

```
Dim MAIN As String() = File.ReadAllLines("")
```

At some point I have one of targets and I need to know what was the tag index (which array line is it), so for example if I have TARGET3 I want to know it's in second line so it's in MAIN(1) and then I can grab TAG = TAG2.

I can't get it working, I tried few methods:

```
Array.IndexOf(MAIN,"TARGET3")
```

always returned -1, it worked with full string tho,

```
Array.IndexOf(MAIN,"TAG2|TARGET3,TARGET4")
```

returned 1. I tried with Array.FindIndex, was the same.

So my question is: how to get index of partial array item. Thank you for any help.

Comment: @Steve, that's the strange thing - if I make MAIN.Contains("TARGET3") it returns false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq to search your array in this way

```
Dim search = "TARGET3"
Dim line = MAIN.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Contains(search))
```

This will return directly the line with the matching word

Comment: @dwarfmine, `Dim search = "TARGET3"
Dim line = MAIN.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Contains(search)` that wont compile, did you notice that? Its missing a **)**. `Dim search = "TARGET3"
Dim line = MAIN.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Contains(search))`...

Comment: Welcome, it happens!